# Sencha Touch 2 multiple route before filters

Tags: sencha-touch-2

Do you know if Sencha Touch has the possibility to implement multiple before filters for routes?

In the code bellow, for the home route, I need to add more that one filter.

Can this be done?

```
Ext.define("TestApp.controller.Router", {

    extend: "Ext.app.Controller",

    config: {
         before: {
            home: 'authenticate, filter2, filter3',
            products: 'authenticate',
            product: 'authenticate',
            testingtwo: 'authenticate'
        },

        routes: {
            '': 'home',
            'home' : 'home',
            'login' : 'login',
            'products' : 'products',
            'products/:id': 'product',
            'testingtwo' : 'testingtwo'
        }
    },
```

Comment: Would you mind giving me some feedback on this answer? Bounty is expiring and I'd like to know if I can improve it or correct it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should put the before filters in an array.

Try this:

```
config: {
     before: {
        home: ['authenticate', 'filter2', 'filter3'],
        products: 'authenticate',
        product: 'authenticate',
        testingtwo: 'authenticate'
    }
}
```

This is the related piece of code in the [Ext.app.Controller](http://docs.sencha.com/touch/2.3.1/source/Controller.html#Ext-app-Controller) sources:

```
/**
 * @private
 * Massages the before filters into an array of function references for each controller action
 */
applyBefore: function(before) {
    var filters, name, length, i;

    for (name in before) {
        filters = Ext.Array.from(before[name]);
        length  = filters.length;

        for (i = 0; i < length; i++) {
            filters[i] = this[filters[i]];
        }

        before[name] = filters;
    }

    return before;
},
```